# How to pass UserId from payment api endpoint to webhook endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, next.js, stripe-payments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv3yq.png)I am using firebase to register new user for SignIn/SignUp etc
I am using stripe CLI.
I have to trigger only the user which is logged in after the payment is done
but at first when I pay the amount with test card then in webhook terminal I can see the userUid at first but when I run the command again in terminal then userUid becomes undefined.

I want to trigger the CLI and then save the triggered events into the firebase database.
it dont go undefined ever
Must pick the currentUser and pass it's userUid in the webhook

Working on nextjs backend and frontend api/stripe/stripe-webhook and api/stripe/stripe/stripe-payment.

api/stripe/stripe-webhook

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "some",
  authDomain: "some",
  projectId: "some",
  storageBucket: "some",
  messagingSenderId: "some",
  appId: "some",
  measurementId: "some",
  databaseURL: "some",
};

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY;
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const sig = req.headers.get("stripe-signature");
    if (!sig) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "No stripe-signature header value was provided." },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    let event;
    let _userUid;
    try {
      const rawBody = await req.text();

      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
      const eventData = JSON.parse(rawBody);
      const userUid = eventData.data.object.metadata.userUid;
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>", event);

      if (userUid !== undefined) {
        _userUid = userUid;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err}`);
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Webhook error" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const codedUid = _userUid;
    const db = getDatabase();
    const userRef = ref(db, `users/${codedUid}/events`);

    try {
      await set(userRef, {
        [event.id]: event.type,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding event to Firebase:", error);
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Firebase error" }, { status: 500 });
    }
    console.log("_userUid:============", _userUid);
```

and

api/stripe/stripe-payment

```
export async function POST(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  const reqBody = await req.json();
  const { amount, metaData } = reqBody;

  if (method === "POST") {
    try {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        metadata: {
          userUid: metaData.userUid,
        },
      });

      // Create checkout session with customer ID
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
        
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: "INV-" + new Date().toISOString(),
              },
              unit_amount: amount * 100 || 100,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        metadata: {
          userUid: metaData.userUid,
          customer: customer.id,
        },
        mode: "payment",

        success_url: `http://localhost:3000/success`,
        cancel_url: `${host}`,
        customer: customer.id,
      });

      const db = getDatabase();
      const userRef = ref(db, `userUids/${Date.now()}`);
      await set(userRef, {
        userUid: metaData.userUid,
        // customerID: customer.id,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      });

      return NextResponse.json({ session });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return new NextResponse(
        { error: "Error creating checkout session" },
        { status: 500 }
      );
    }
  } else {
    return new NextResponse({ error: "Method Not Allowed" }, { status: 405 });
  }
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add metadata via the CLI, you will need to use the `trigger` command's [`--add` flag](https://docs.stripe.com/cli/trigger#trigger-add)

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded --add payment_intent:metadata[some_key]=some_value
```

If you are creating a Checkout Session and want your metadata to appear on the resulting payment intent, you will need to pass that metadata into the Checkout Session's [`payment_intent_data.metadata` parameter](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata). Metadata is not automatically copied between related Stripe objects, so Stripe's API has special parameters like `payment_intent_data` to allow setting metadata on an object other than the one that you are directly working with.